# Loop over lists and concat in pd.dataframe

Tags: numpy, pandas

I'm trying to mulitply a DataFrame with a numpy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import*
import pandas as pd

C = np.arange(30).reshape(5, 6)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(48).reshape((8, 6)), columns=list('abcdef'))
pxc = df / df.shift(1) - 1

def concatArrays(A, B):
     cArrays_0 = np.sum(A[0,]*B, axis=1)
     cArrays_1 = np.sum(A[1,]*B, axis=1)
     cArrays_2 = np.sum(A[2,]*B, axis=1)
     cArrays_3 = np.sum(A[3,]*B, axis=1)
     cArrays_4 = np.sum(A[4,]*B, axis=1)
     #(...)

     pieces = [cArrays_0, cArrays_1, cArrays_2, cArrays_3, cArrays_4] #(...)
     concatenated = concat(pieces, axis=1, join='outer')
     return concatenated

print concatArrays(C, pxc)
```

I would like to create a loop so that 'concatenated is automatic regardless of the number of lists in C, avoiding writing each cArray_i by hand.

Thanx

Comment: *How* do you want to multiply something of shape `(5, 6)` with something of shape `(8, 6)` ?

Comment: I would like to multiply each column in pxc by the respective number in each list of A. Ex. the first column (a) in pxc by the first number in the first list of A, then multiply the second column by the second number, etc. until the last column of both the df and the ndaray, creating a dataframe. That then would become a column after applying the np.sum, axis=1 to the df creating a column(ndarray?). And then concatenate(?) the various columns that would be created for each list in A, creating the final dataframe, with the same index as pxc.

Comment: No need to import pandas twice, just `import pandas as pd` will do, you can remove the line `from pandas import *`

Comment: @askewchan thanx. Any suggestions?Do you know if this can be done?

Comment: @Pedro9 No sorry, I actually don't know pandas, just saw the double import :P

Answer (score 0):

Strongly suspect that

```
def concatArrays(A, B):

     pieces = [a*B for a in A] #(...)
     concatenated = concat(pieces, axis=1, join='outer')
     return concatenated
```

will do the trick, but it will depend on if `pandas` behaves as  I expect it to in terms of iterating over data frames.